# Skipping multiple hooks on a commit message?

Tags: git, hook, webhooks

I am having trouble committing some work i've done because i have some commit hooks that are causing me trouble. Often these hooks are useful, but at times they are not. I have two in particular that are causing me problems right now, these being both CoffeeLint and also RuboCop.

In the past when I have had a snag with one of them, and wanted to disregard their suggestions i've ran

```
SKIP=RuboCop git commit -m "my commit message"
```

This works well, I am able to commit my work, and progress with whatever I am doing.

However this time, with what I've been working on, i've worked with some deep rails code, and also some angular coffee-script code and as a result triggered two hooks to be flagged in my attempt to commit something.

These hooks now are RuboCop and CoffeeLint

I've tried running

```
SKIP=CoffeeLint, RuboCop git commit -m "my commit message"
SKIP=CoffeeLintRuboCop git commit -m "my commit message"
SKIP=(CoffeeLint, RuboCop) git commit -m "my commit message"
SKIP=CoffeeLint && RuboCop git commit -m "my commit message"  
SKIP=CoffeeLint, SKIP=RuboCop git commit -m "my commit message"
```

All of these attempts have not worked out for me.

The only other option I have right now besides asking around is uninstalling coffeelint and rubocop (which I'd rather not do)

Would anybody know if there is a possible solution to this interesting situation?

Comment: I know nothing about the hooks you're using, but in general the syntax `var=value command arg1 arg2 ...` looks like sh/bash style "set environment variable for duration of command".  If—this is a very big if—your hook accepts multiple `SKIP=` values, they're probably comma-separated but you can't insert white space, e.g., `SKIP=a,b,c git commit ...`.  That aside, you can always have `git commit` skip the pre-commit and commit-msg hooks entirely by adding `-n` or `--no-verify` to your `git commit` arguments.

Comment: Oh thank you so much! That ended up working out for me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SKIP=CoffeeLint,RuboCop git commit -m "my commit message"
```

Comment: Ha, I wrote that such a long time ago. Now whenever I run into that problem I just go SKIP=all or individually SKIP=RuboCop etc